# Laravel 6 - Property [proyectos_id] does not exist on this collection instance, a pesar de si existir

Tags: php, sql, laravel, laravel-blade, laravel-6

Tengo un código que se supone que muestra información asociada a un proyecto (sus textos e imágenes), dicho código es el siguiente:

index_proyecto.blade.php

```php
Mostrando el proyecto {{ $proyecto->nombre_proyecto }}

                <br>

                <div class="row pt-4">
                    <h3>Textos</h3>
                    @foreach($texto as $txt)
                        @foreach($texto_proyecto as $txt_prt)
                            @if($texto_proyecto->proyectos_id == $proyecto->id)
                                <br>
                                <div class="col-2">
                                    <h5>{{ $txt->caption }}</h5>
                                    <p>{{ $txt->texto }}</p>
                                </div>
                                <br>
                            @endif
                        @endforeach
                    @endforeach
                </div>
```

Se supone que, por cada texto que existe y por cada texto asociado a un proyecto (usando una tabla intermedia), si el id en la asociación es el mismo id que en el proyecto previamente elegido.

Pero, como el titulo sugiere, el error que sale es el siguiente:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Pensé que era un problema en el controller, pero según yo esta correcto:

ProyectoController.php

```php
public function index($proyecto)
    {
        $proyecto = \App\Proyectos::findorfail($proyecto);

        $texto = Textos::all();

        $image = Imagenes::all();

        $texto_proyecto = Textos_Proyectos::all();

        $imagen_proyecto = Imagenes_Proyectos::all();

        return view::make('proyectos.index_proyecto')
             ->with(compact('texto'))
             ->with(compact('proyecto'))
             ->with(compact('image'))
             ->with(compact('texto_proyecto'))
             ->with(compact('imagen_proyecto'))
            ;
    }
```

(Tambien hice las exportaciones con use App/nombre_clase)

También me aseguré que el nombre de la tabla, proyectos_id, fuera el correcto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y la verdad estoy confundido, ¿que es lo que estoy haciendo mal?

Comment: Esas tablas estan relacionadas cierto?, puedes mostrar tus modelos?

Comment: Ojo que si buscas obtener datos de tablas relacionadas está es la menos óptima forma de hacerlo 4 consultas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cambia esta linea:

```php
@if($texto_proyecto->proyectos_id == $proyecto->id)
```

Por esta:

```php
@if($txt_prt->proyectos_id == $proyecto->id)
```

Creo que es allí donde esta el error por que estas accediendo directamente al `collection` de `texto_proyectos`

Comment: No sé como no me di cuenta, muchas gracias compadre